# Socket.io - Don't allow client to view files with the main.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am currently working on a project which uses `socket.io` with `NodeJS` to control something else. This is my code so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');

var contents = fs.readFileSync("data.json");
var remoteLayout = JSON.parse(contents);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

app.get('/edit', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/edit.html');

});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

});


http.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

It is my code shortened to the parts which are relevant.

So my question is, when I run this code in node, and I open the page `[myIPAddress]:8080` it opens up `index.html` like it should and at the top of Chrome, it says `[myIPAddress]:8080`. Now if I to the bar which shows the page's URL at the top, and change that to `[myIPAddress]:8080/handler.js` it opens a page with my js script printed out on it. How do I make it so that the person cannot go to that `[myIPAddress]:8080/handler.js` page?

I'm not sure if it matters, but the folder with the `main.js` file has also `index.html`, `edit.html`, and `handler.js`.

Comment: You'd have to check the `referer` header when a request is made for a .js file and handle the response appropriately. Of course, using developer tools, anyone could see the js loaded in the page anyway, so, why bother attempting to hide js code - you can't make it invisible

Comment: So would I have to check this for each file? Also I am new to this, so how do I check the referer header - is that the `app.get(...)`? I realize that developer tools allow the viewer to view the code anyway, but this is more for my curiosity...

Comment: I would've thought you  do the checking in an app.get with a regular expression to catch files ending in '.js' as the first argument - but, that's justa guess

Comment: Thanks, I get it... I'll leave the question open just in case there is a socket.io predefined way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

When you do that, you've exposed all files in the `__dirname` directory for anyone to see including your server files that are located in that directory.  Instead, you should move your static files that you intend for the public to have access to to some other directory and then use:

```
app.use(express.static(someOtherPath));
```

This will keep your server files in `__dirname` private and expose only the files you intend to be public that you have located in someOtherPath.

---

If handler.js is actually intended for use in your web pages and thus must be made available to the browser, then you cannot prevent anyone from looking at it.  If your webpage needs to use it, then the browser must be able to download it and if the browser must be able to download it, then you cannot prevent a person from seeing it.  You can do all sorts of things like obscure it to make it less intelligible to a person, but to any determined hacker, the logic will still all be there and you can't hide any Javascript intended to run in a browser.

Logic that you want to protect MUST be only on your server, perhaps usable via Ajax calls.  You can't keep code secret that must run in a browser.